# Changes in template files, Magento

Tags: html, css, magento-1.7

I'm new to magento. For themes I'm changing the html and css in template files. What will happen when I upgrade magento?
I don't know much about magento.

kindly help me to do it in good way.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this nice tutorial about how to upgrade.

They Say:

> 1) STUDY Change LOG
>
> You should familiarize yourself with any new changes and modifications
>   to the latest version of application you need to upgrade. Upgrading an
>   applications requires complete knowledge of the new features and
>   modifications made in that application.
>
> 2) KEEPING BACK UP OF PREVIOUS VERSION BEFORE UPGRADING
>
> Its always better to be on a safe side rather than to regret
>   afterwards. You should always maintain a complete back up of all the
>   previous files, folders, packages and database before upgrading any
>   application.
>
> 3) KEEP THE OLDER SOURCE HANDY
>
> You never know when the new upgraded version of applications stops
>   working, So its better to keep your older source always ready to use
>   in case of any problem or suddenly the newer sources doesn't functions
>   properly.

**When you're studying the changelog you can see if the way of implementing themes/templates are changed. if not you can just copy the template files over to your newly installerd magento.**

http://www.medma.net/knowledge-base/index.php?title=2&article=1